# split data on a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I got a column that got data which is comma separated like that

connect,ae8:2030-3062,bras02-ram,0

and need to split it into 3 columns one with 'connect' and second with 'ae8:2030-3062' and third with 'bras02-ram'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method of `pd.Series`

```py
df[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df['column_name'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```